# Create a backdrop in react native

Tags: css, react-native, layout

I have a bottom bar to which i want to add this [kind of background in react native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w48R.png) currently it [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWdRT.png).

How do i achieve this

This is my current code

```
<View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Image
                  style={tabStyle.iconSize}
                  source={require('../assets/List-icon-1.png')}
                />
                <Image
                  style={tabStyle.arrowSize}
                  source={require('../assets/Arrow-1-1.png')}
                />
              </View>

const tabStyle = StyleSheet.create({
iconSize: {
height: 35,
width: 35,
marginBottom: 5,
},
arrowSize: {
height: 17,
width: 15,
marginBottom: 5,
},
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a component for this.

> Using Yarn

```
yarn add react-native-linear-gradient
```

> Using Npm

```
npm install react-native-linear-gradient --save
```

after that

```
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

// Within your render function
<LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
    Sign in with Facebook
  </Text>
</LinearGradient>

// Later on in your styles..
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Gill Sans',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#ffffff',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});
```

if doesnt work u can commet for help ^^

Comment: tried it it seems i cant pass any other component apart from tab screen to tab navigator
if you see it is kind of a radial blur

Comment: <LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
  // Your bottom bar code  and u can change opacity for like your reference image
</LinearGradient>

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this in tabBar options prop in your tabBar component

```
    tabBarOptions={{
       activeTintColor: '#fff',
       inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
       activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
       inactiveBackgroundColor: '#fff',
           style: {
                 backgroundColor: '#white',
               
           }
    }}
>
```

Comment: no actually it was not about position of icons i got that right it was about the blurred background that you see behind the first icon